# How to use Frames and Listboxes for an Entry widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, frames

My code uses the frame method to structure my Username widget label and entry. My label is called "unLab" and the entry is called "username". 
The frame for my username widget is called usernameFrame.

However, I would like to alter the entry box and turn into a listbox, but also keeping the frame. How would I be able do to this?

What I tried to do is right below. 
If I write username = Entry(END, item),
It would return "str isn't recognised as tk". 
 Thanks

```
listbox = Listbox(usernameFrame)
listbox.pack(side = TOP)

listbox.insert(END, "usernames")

for item in ["username1", "username2"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
```

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.title("OCR PPP Program that EVALUATES a student's details")
usernameFrame = Frame(root)
usernameFrame.pack(side = TOP)
large_font = ("Calibri,40")
unLab = Label(usernameFrame,text="Enter username: ",fg="light green",bg="green",font = "Calibri 26 italic",bd=1, relief="solid")
unLab.pack(side = LEFT)
username = Entry(usernameFrame,font=large_font)
username.pack(side = LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"to alter the entry box and turn into a listbox"*: Means, you want to `.destroy()` the `Entry` and replace it with a `Listbox`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to look for is a Combobox. This is a widget present in `tkinter.ttk`. A combobox provides a list of values that can be selected from or user required text in an entry. I have edited your code to replace the entry with a combobox which has 3 options: username1, username2, & other.

```py
uname = StringVar()
username = Combobox(root, textvariable = uname, values = ["username1", "username2", "other"])
username.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", usernameSelect)
username.pack(side = LEFT)
```

This function is called whenever a new value from the list is selected, and enables the editing mode if the value selected was 'other' ( `state='normal'` means editing mode )

```
def usernameSelect(event):
if uname.get() not in ["username1", "username2"]:
    username.config(state = 'normal')
    uname.set('')
else:
    username.config(state = 'readonly')
```

Now just use `uname.get()` method to get the value in the `Combobox`. 
Here is the full code

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

def usernameSelect(event):
    if uname.get() not in ["username1", "username2"]:
        username.config(state = 'normal')
        uname.set('')
    else:
        username.config(state = 'readonly')

root= Tk()
root.title("OCR PPP Program that EVALUATES a student's details")
usernameFrame = Frame(root)
usernameFrame.pack(side = TOP)
large_font = ("Calibri,40")
unLab = Label(usernameFrame,text="Enter username: ",fg="light green",bg="green",font = "Calibri 26 italic",bd=1, relief="solid")
unLab.pack(side = LEFT)
uname = StringVar()
username = Combobox(root, textvariable = uname, values = ["username1", "username2", "other"] )
username.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", usernameSelect)
username.pack(side = LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Works perfectly!!